# Getting a "No instance of Applicative" error when declaring a Monad

Tags: haskell, types, monads

I'm trying to implement the example from the first chapter of [this paper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/828035/Monads/monads.pdf), which goes like this:

```
data Tree a = Fork (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a | Nil deriving (Show)

instance Monad Tree where
   return a = Leaf a
   Nil >>= f = Nil
   Leaf a >>= f = f a
   Fork u v >>= f = Fork (u >>= f) (v >>= f)

tree1 = Fork 
         (Fork (Leaf 2) Nil) 
         (Fork (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3))

tree2 = Fork (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)

f 2 = Fork Nil (Leaf "Two")
f 3 = Fork (Leaf "Three") (Leaf "String")

tree3 = tree2 >>= f
```

When I run it in GHC, I get this error:

```
monads.hs:3:10:
    No instance for (Applicative Tree)
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monad Tree’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I've tried adding this to the beginning

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

but I get this error:

```
monads.hs:7:10:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘Monad’
    It could refer to either ‘Main.Monad’, defined at monads.hs:1:1
                          or ‘Prelude.Monad’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at monads.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
```

What is the most correct fix?

Comment: You cannot define a class (`Monad` or something else) twice...

Comment: Since that paper, `Monad` gained an `Applicative` dependency.  You should be able to implement it just with `ap` and `return`, though.

Comment: To be really, really explicit about it, the problem you're experiencing is that this code worked in older versions of Haskell, but not anymore in very recent versions of GHC. Recent versions don't allow you to define a `Monad` instance unless the type in question also has `Functor` and `Applicative` instances as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, like the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) specifies. The `Monad` class signature is:

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    --...
```

This means that in order to define the instance of a type to be `Monad`, you first need to define that type to be `Applicative`. The problem is even more severe since the [signature of `Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Applicative) states:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    --...
```

So you first need to make `Tree` an instance of `Functor`. The reason that in the paper, this wasn't necessary, is because - as far as I know, in the early versions of `Prelude` these constraints were not necessary.

Now in order to let it work, we first make `Tree` an instance of `Functor`. We therefore need to define a function `fmap`, which - for a given function `f :: a -> b`, maps a `Tree a` to a `Tree b`:

```
instance Functor Tree where
   fmap f (Leaf a) = Leaf $ f a
   fmap f (Fork u v) = Fork (fmap f u) (fmap f v)
   fmap _ Nil = Nil
```

Now that we have defined this, we can define `Applicative`:

```
instance Applicative Tree where
    pure = Leaf
    (<*>) (Leaf f) = fmap f
    (<*>) Nil = const $ Nil
```

and finally we can define the `Monad` instance:

```
instance Monad Tree where
   return a = Leaf a
   Nil >>= f = Nil
   Leaf a >>= f = f a
   Fork u v >>= f = Fork (u >>= f) (v >>= f)
```

Comment: Do all monad instances require this same kind of hierarchical definition?  (Functor, Applicative, Monad)?

Comment: @MarkKaravan: you need to define all three of them if you use the latest version of `base` (most of the stuff in `Prelude`). But - as in most programming languages - you can of course write them in any order you like in your file.

Comment: @MarkKaravan, fortunately, most people find `Monad` instance declarations to be a very small portion of their code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Not only that, but you can also define them "backwards", so first implement `Monad` and implement functor and applicative based on the monad operators (this isn't always good, but it can save a bit of time).

Comment: @Cubic: well you can indeed for instance use a cyclic definition like luqui shows). But you have to define all the instances `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`. My point was to show how one could implement these instances. Introducing all kinds of library functions is indeed how one can do it, but you do not see what's behind these functions.

Answer (score 11):

To expand on Louis Wasserman's comment, you need to add an `Applicative` (and therefore `Functor`) instance now when you are declaring a `Monad` instance.  Once you have written the `Monad` instance, the other instances are always the same:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM, ap)

instance Functor Tree where
    fmap = liftM
instance Applicative Tree where 
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

This changed because every `Monad` is an `Applicative` (using this instance), but not the other way around, so it's morally a superclass. However, `Applicative` was added to the standard library after `Monad` so it wasn't made a real superclass for a long time since that would break people's code.  Recently, since `Applicative` has come into very common use, the community decided to make `Applicative` a real superclass of `Monad`, breaking everybody's code once but improving it for the future.  So that's what you're seeing.